# How do we call the way we work with php?

Tags: php, url-routing

I have maybe a strange question but I just need to know,

When using PHP there are a lot of ways to build a application or website. My question how do we call this build models?

I list some ways I know and maybe someone knows how they are called:

- An index with a application view. Every action is posted to a PHP file like delete action goes to delete.php and a insert action is posted to insert.php and so on. When finished we use the `header('location: index.php');` to return to our view.
- An index.php with above a long list of if/else or switch statements looking for an action to be called. If action get called like `index.php?action=delete` the action gets performed and than we create the view. If there is no action call we just make the view.
- A index file with only basic html it calls the view with ajax from an other php file like action.php?action=start. Every interaction goes trough action.php using ajax to load the result into the index html page.
- The url gets rewrite by .httacces like `website.com/delete/` -> `website.com/index.php?action=delete` And then everything goes trough index.php. When a action like delete gets called a file that preforms the action gets included like `if($_REQUEST['action'] == 'delete'){ include(delete.php); }` and at least a view is created.

How are these methods called? Is there a documentation for this?

I am conducting a research to all different ways of working with PHP. Of course I try to lay out a list of advantages and disadvantages and witch way is best or good to use. I know one way of working is called Model view Control in short MVC. But how are the other methods called and where can I find some information about these methods. Especially methods only used for PHP programming because the MVC model is used in a lot of languages.

Comment: This may be more suited to programmers.stackexchange.com which is more targetted for conceptual questions, SO is aimed at real world programming problems

Comment: What you're describing aren't really "features" of PHP, more loose patterns adopted by various frameworks. Some of these frameworks may use an MVC approach, but this is a very broad term.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Martin Fowler calls the first design a ["page controller"](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/pageController.html) and your #2 + #4 would then respectively be called ["front controller"](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/frontController.html).

It can be hard to draw a clear line between when it's one or the other design as they tend to overlap quite a bit (Your ajax example is a good example - You sort of have two front controllers in there).

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I was looking for. Very interesting link to http://martinfowler.com/ I will use this in my quest. Thank you for the crystal clear answer.